# Rabbitmq pika.BasicProperties don't send properties in message

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I'm using pika to send message to rabbitmq.
I need to send additional properties so I'm using pika.BasicProperties, but when I see this message in Wireshark there are no properties added.

My code:

```
import pika, uuid

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='test_60', durable=True, arguments={'x-message-ttl' : 21600000})

routingKey = "test_server"
message = '{"test_int":268,"Timestamp":1610022012203}'

correlation_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
reply_to = "test_60"
message_type = "SendRequest"

channel.basic_publish(exchange='',routing_key=routingKey,
                body=message,properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                headers={"testId": "60"},
                delivery_mode=2,
                correlation_id = correlation_id,
                reply_to = reply_to,
                type = message_type))

print('message sent')
print(correlation_id)
```

In Wireshark this message looks like this, so there are no properties and I have no idea what is wrong with this example.

[image]

Comment: Just to know - on what basis are you sure that this is the package to publish your message ?

Comment: I am sure because I send only this one message, there is no other Basic.Publish message in history

Comment: Still - I'm not convinced that this is a proper method to check if properties are sent. In the screenshot you attached there is no message body - so you can say that you don't send body neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
 prop = pika.BasicProperties(
            content_type='application/json',
            content_encoding='utf-8',
            headers={'key': 'value'},
            delivery_mode = 1,
        )

        channel.basic_publish(
                exchange='',
                routing_key=qname,
                properties=prop,
                body='{message: hello}'
            )
```

UI:

[image]

Wireshark:

[image]